# Metacryptic ep. 4

Tags: cryptic-clues

**Yo dawg, I heard you like cryptic clues ...**

Solve these cryptic clues to reveal (and solve) the final clue.

1. Well-built steam ship heads East with subtlety (7)
2. Cost catches new net tournament (7)
3. Begins amidst messy trash twist (6, 4)
4. "[Green light objectives incomplete, chief (2, 5)]?"

(5)

<sub>To clarify: The quotes and question mark are for the final clue. Clue 4 is completely contained within the square brackets, which are *not* part of the final clue.</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Well-built steam ship heads East with subtlety (7)
```

> **FINESSE**   (Well-built [FINE] steam ship heads [SS] East [E]; subtlety [*def.*])

```
Cost catches new net tournament (7)
```

> **CONTEST**   from **[@Will](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48909/30633)**

```
Begins amidst messy trash twist (6, 4)
```

> **STARTS WITH**   from **[@Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48906/30633)**

```
Green light objectives incomplete, chief (2, 5)
```

> **GO AHEAD**   (Green light [*def.*]; objectives incomplete [GOA(ls)] + chief [HEAD])

**Meta**

> ***Finesse contest starts with "Go ahead?" (5)***
>  **GRACE**   (G(o) + RACE)     (from **@Will** in TSL)

Answer (score 6):

3 is

> Starts with

Because

> Messy trash twist indicates an anagram of 'trash twist' which is 'starts with'. Begins amidst is the def

Answer (score 5):

### Partial answer

Cost catches new net tournament (7)

> CO(NTE*)ST